# IRC Channel for New Questions?

Tags: feature-request, irc

It would be very fun if there was an IRC channel in which all new questions on SO were listed (title, tags, and (clickable) URL) automatically upon their creation.

Comment: There was - is it dead now? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/what-about-the-irc-channel

Comment: @Dominic Rodger: As far as I can see, new questions at SO are *not* posted in #stackoverflow.

Comment: they *were* though. At one time, there was a bot that posted each new question as it appeared on the site. Worked great when SO was young, but I suspect the huge volume of traffic killed it - even a year ago when I last checked in, it was noisy enough to seriously hamper other conversation.

Comment: There still is for for serverfault. (#serverfault on freenode)

Comment: For those finding this via Google: #serverfault is now completely defunct (registered to ChanServ, last use Feb. 2011, no ops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a possibility with the new StackOverflow API. Currently it is in Semi-Private Beta, so look for it to be released in the upcoming months.

I'm sure someone will do something like this by checking the new questions feed as often as the API allows (or once every 10-30 seconds).

This would probably be a fairly easy thing to implement.